# Getting a shot on Shabbat to prepare one to save a life after Shabbat

Tags: shabbat, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, hachana-prep-for-weekday

Related
[Can we violate Shabbos to inject a vaccine?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48637/can-we-violate-shabbos-to-inject-a-vaccine)

This is not a current situation, but reflects a real set of circumstances that does actually happen.

Assuming (as the linked question does) that getting a shot poses a problem on Shabbat, can one get a shot that prepares one to save a life after Shabbat? Note -- not to have one's life saved after Shabbat but to participate in saving someone else's life after Shabbat.

Is the shot (in addition to any other problem) hachana for after Shabbat or is hachana suspended if the preparation is to save a life? What if the saving is not 100% inevitable?

Are there other questions one would have to ask to be able to decide the permissibility of getting the shot?

Comment: Can this be done before/after Shabbos? If not, then why wouldn't it be considered a part of the Pikuach Nefesh permission?

Comment: @Salmononius2 if the schedule is established by a doctor (8AM, everyday) then that's when it has to be done. But the piku'ach nefesh is not until A) after Shabbat and B) well after Shabbat and one could even make the argument that the P"N is not a 100% certainty.

Comment: People who have diabetes get shots on shabbat; no?