# Sources for the halachos of medical emergencies on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, medicine, health-safety-shmira, choleh-sick

As I've mentioned [elsewhere](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=18693080#18693080), I'm currently preparing a *chabura* (presentation) on the laws of medical emergencies on Shabbos.

What sources discuss the halachos of medicine on Shabbos?

Comment: This is supposed to be a [crowd-sourced database](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48037/5323), so if you can add to the answer below, please do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer, which means that anyone with 100 reputation points or more can edit without review. Please feel free to add your own sources, keeping the structure I've set up. Also, please leave a comment regarding your addition, so that it's clear who said what :)

#### Gemara

- **[Yoma 85a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=6&daf=85&format=pdf)-b** (*which verse teaches that we violate שבת to save a life; וחי בהם ולא שימות בהם*)
- **[Shabbos 107b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=107b&format=pdf)** (*popping pimples and containing dangerous snakes on Shabbos*)
- **[Shabbos 30a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=30&format=pdf)** (*extinguishing candles for patients is only for the dangerously ill, but for the חולה שאין בו סכנה extinguishing candles is פטור אבל אסור*)

#### Rishonim

- **Rikanti 166** (*some rabbis felt that treatments that will not certainly heal the patient do not supersede Shabbos/Yom Kippur; they are dead wrong* [pun intended, see there ;-)])
- **Tosfos to [Sukkah 26a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=7&daf=26&format=pdf) (sv ואפילו)** (*danger to limb = danger to life, even for Chillul Shabbos*)
- **Meiri to [Shabbos 29b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=29b&format=pdf)**

#### Rambam

- **[Rambam Hilchos Shabbos chapter 2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=3&hilchos=12&perek=2&halocha=)**

#### Shulchan Aruch

- **[Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 307:5](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1528)** (*you can tell a gentile to do a rabbinnic violation for someone who is "mildly sick"*)
- **[Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 328](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1596)** (*general laws of sick people on Shabbos*)
- **[Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 329](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1602)** (*for whom we violate Shabbos*)
- **[Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 330](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1602)** (*childbirth on Shabbos*)

#### Recent Publications

- **Shemiras Shabbos K'hilchasa** ([Rabbi Yehoshua Yeshaya Neuwirth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yehoshua_Neuwirth)) **chapters 32-41** (*all laws, especially practical applications in the modern era*) [ ***Note:*** some outdated technical information ]
- **Hilchos Rofim uRefuah** (rulings of the Tzitz Eliezer [Rabbi Eliezer Yehudah Waldenburg] on medical halachos, compiled by Rabbi Dr. Avraham Steinberg) **Sha'ar 2** (*all laws, especially practical applications in the modern era*)
- **[Nishmas Avraham](http://hebrewbooks.org/51473)** (Rabbi Dr. Abraham Abraham) Orach Chayim, in all the sections that deal with Shabbos. (*all laws, especially practical applications in the modern era*) [ ***Note:*** the older editions contain outdated technical information ]
- **[Halachot for the Patient on the Sabbath, Festivals and Yom-Kippur](http://store.medethics.org.il/index.php/books-in-english/halachot-for-the-patient-on-the-sabbath-festivals-and-yom-kippur.html)** (Rabbi Dr. Abraham Abraham) available in both Hebrew and English
- [**Halacha uRefuah**](http://hebrewbooks.org/49903) by Rav Moshe Hershler, published 1981 (h/t Yishai)

A lot of the sources came from the [source sheet](http://www.yutorah.org/download.cfm?materialID=513055) for [this shiur](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/783536/Rabbi_Hershel_Schachter/Emergency_Situations_on_Shabbos) by Rav Herschel Shachter, and some from [the local ENT](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38326/does-use-of-bi-lateral-cochlear-implants-eliminate-the-definition-of-a-cheresh/40110#comment105637_40110).