# Does anyone distinguish between hearing megillah over analog vs digital technology

Tags: purim, technology, megillat-esther

As [discussed previously](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/128524/does-hearing-the-megillah-over-the-internet-fulfill-the-mitzvah), there were minority opinions about fulfilling the mitzvah of megillah by hearing it over a microphone, telephone, radio, or online.

Have any poskim drawn the line between analog technologies and digital ones? The latter are one more step removed from the original.

Comment: What is an analog technology in this regard?

Comment: but the digital technologies give better reproduction.

Comment: Let's say radio (FM or AM), which is actually as I understand it pretty much unchanged from when R' Ovadya Yosef zt"l and his predecessors talked about hearing megillah that way. (Assuming it's still a good-old analog channel.) For a microphone, I think you can still buy analog or digital ones.